# php base64_encode without the = sign

Tags: php, base64

I'm using the base64_encode function to hash strings. The strings must be a-zA-Z0-9 and sometimes base64_encode outputs the = sign at the end (sometimes twice).

What is the most efficient way to alter the base64_encode function (override?) to omit the = signs?

Comment: in addition: there is no need for my program to decode the strings back to original form

Comment: Why would you `base64`-encode something that you don't want to decode again? Perhaps a hash-function (such as `md5` or `sha1`) might be the more suitable thing here.

Comment: then maybe you need some hashing function instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The possible `=`s at the end are **required** if you want to decode the value later. Also, the character set `a-zA-Z0-9` has only 62 values and thus a base-**64** encoded value can never fit inside it.

**Update:** If you need to hash strings, why not use a hash function? `md5` should be a good go-to solution unless the application is security-sensitive, in which case a stronger hash (`sha1` or better) should be used.

Comment: i just added that in a comment. i knew someone will point it out :)

Comment: @Tom: You still need to account for the other two characters (I believe `/` and `+` are used). And why use `base64_encode` if you are going to mutilate its output? Maybe some other tool is more suited to the task? What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Tom: Then use a hash function :)

Answer (score 1):

As Jon said you need the `=` to decode it later but from what you say you don't need to do that, in which case your better off using `md5` instead, this will give you a 32 character A-F/0-9 string.